# How can I vertically center this content?

Tags: html, css

I know there are a bunch of questions about this already but none of the solutions actually work for my particular situation. This is what the layout looks like without any fixes for vertical centering: http://jsfiddle.net/4FsKG/9/

This is with **tr#toolBar**: **height** and **line-height** set to *2.25em*: http://jsfiddle.net/4FsKG/10/. This centers everything but the border around my page numbers results in a gap that you can easily notice under the borders on the left. In addition, the border takes up the whole height of the cell instead of just being around the numbers as intended.

I've tried numerous other solutions to the problem but all of them end up as some variation of the two examples I've already shown.

I would like everything in the row to be centered vertically while allowing me to put a border around things like my page numbers. Anyone have any ideas?

The CSS for my example:

```
table {
    background-color:#274F68;
    font-size:0.85em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border:1px solid #274F68;
    border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

tr#input td { border-bottom:2px solid #6189A3; }

    tr#input td form {
        float:right;        
    }

tr#toolBar { 
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:#152939;
    color:#6189A3;
}

    tr#toolBar td { border-bottom:2px solid #6189A3; }

        tr#toolBar td a {
            padding:0;
            margin:0 3px 0 3px;
        }

.dataTables_length { float:left;}
.dataTables_info { float:left; }
.dataTables_filter { float:right; }
.dataTables_paginate { float:right; }

.paging_full_numbers a.paginate_button,
.paging_full_numbers a.paginate_active {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #6189A3;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this without tables?

Comment: @Jason I have not. I considering moving these sections out of the table but then that would has a pretty major drawback: I'd have to explicitly define my table width.

Comment: The problem is that your page numbers have a border on top and bottom but your other elements in that row do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace floats with `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle` and that will do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/4FsKG/42/

But don't forget to also add `_display: inline; zoom:1;` if you want to support IE7 and below.

Comment: What if I want the length/info elements positioned to the left and the filter/pagination elements positioned to the right? It also looks like the border next to the info element doesn't take up the entire height of the table row.

Comment: Then stick with your second option (height + line-height) and just add wrappers for numbers to get proper borders: http://jsfiddle.net/4FsKG/43/

Comment: I actually figured out a solution. I simply set line-height for the row to my value and then set line-height for the links to none and it works perfectly. Since your answer/solution would've gotten me on the right track anyways I'm going to accept it. Just please add in the additional details.